# TYPO3 7.6.4 backend language not changing/downloading

Tags: typo3

I installed TYPO3 7.6.4 (LTS). I then went to backend, downloaded German language and under User preferences i changed my admin language to "German". After clearing the caches and relogging, nothing has changed.

TYPO3 tells me that the language files have been downloaded successfully, but there is no data in the directory `typo3conf/l10n/`
it's just empty. All folder access rights are `777`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you clear System cache as well ? Translation files depends on it massively

Comment: You must delete all the files from the folder typo3temp/Cache/Data/l10n/. Look there for the recently downloaded language files.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable "curlUse" from backend installtool or in LocalConfiguration.php

```
'SYS' => [
   'curlUse' => '1',
]
```

For example:-> [image]
So After that you will be able to download language as well as available translation files of extensions.

After that you can enable it from user settings 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you have use the "user Settings" button at the Top?

[image]

Comment: yeah i already changed everything possible there. Whats weird is, after i added a second admin user and changed his language to German it works. But only with the user i added as second one. The first one still does not work.

Comment: you can try to reset the user config with button "Reset user settings to default state"? Or delete and recreate the admin user in install tool.